# Windows 8 XAML Objects and Snapped View

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

So I have made an app and set the layout so it appears ok in portrait mode. For the snapped view I created a ListView that contains different instances of the same objects. This ListView is initially collapsed and then when it changes to snapped the listview becomes visible and the portrait mode objects become collapsed.

This works fine, but as they are two different sets of objects it messes up the user experience. If they enter text into the boxes in portrait mode and then switch to snapped view all of their text will have gone (as they put it in the now collapsed text box).

The question is is it possible to just change the position / size of the elements so that they are the same objects just in a different place, depending on if we're in snapped mode or not?

Hope this is clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in fact, that functionality is built-in to the `LayoutAwarePage` class, which is the type of [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.aspx) you get when you add a Basic Page (vs. Blank Page) to your project. If you started with the Grid or Split App template, the provided pages likewise extend `LayoutAwarePage`.

These pages have some boilerplate XAML that leverages the [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and defines states for the various application layouts.  What you can do is design your layout for the full landscape mode and then use the [Device window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215600.aspx#Step_3__Adapt_the_page_layout_to_different_orientations_and_views) to record changes to your layout (placement, colors, etc.) for Snapped, Filled, and Portrait.

For instance, here's a simple UI in landscape mode:

[image]

Then by switching *Visual state* to **Snapped** and turning on *Enable State Recording*, I made changes to the layout:

[image]

At runtime, the app looks like the following in each of the two states.  No code needed - it's all being handled by `LayoutAwarePage` switching between VisualStates as the orientation of the app changes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried to add the XAML objects to a list view whilst "Enable State Recording" was enabled but it would not let me, giving the error "When recording into a Storyboard or a property trigger you may not change the parent-child structure of the scene." I could just move the position of the objects, but this would not allow it to scroll if it gets too long for the snapped screen. Do you know of a way of achieving it automatically moving and making it so it can scroll up and down? Thanks.

Comment: You could place elements in a ScrollViewer a StackPanel from the get go but I'd be cautious on the use of scrolling - particularly vertically (unless it's something like a list of items).

Comment: I seem to be having a problem with one of my pages. http://i.imgur.com/FpzGw.png I can't select between the different page states. The page does inherit from LayoutAwarePage and in the XAML different ApplicationViewStates have been created, as specified here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj129464.aspx . I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working, it did work for one of my other pages just fine. Would you have any ideas on what to check for first?

Comment: I managed to 'fix' it. For some reason it wanted the XAML to be at the top, just below `<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}"/>` even though in the other file it did work in it is at the bottom. Which is strange because when I went on to the States panel in Blend and tried to add a state called "ApplicationViewStates" it kept renaming it to "ApplicationViewStates1", so it knew that there was already a state there.